# REST WCF service returns XML response but not JSON response

Tags: wcf

I am new to WCF so I think this is pretty basic. I have a simple method that a single "order" object is returned. It works just fine when using the default XML, however, when I apply the

```
ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json
```

attribute, it fails to return `JSON`.  The code successfully executes and hits the return line but then the method is immediately called again and then finally a third time before the browser returns an error stating **the connection to localhost has been interrupted**.

When I remove the `ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json`,  the method is called and XML is returned just fine.  Not sure I am missing for the JSON.

**IProductSales.cs**

```
namespace ProductsSalesService
{
    [ServiceContract(Name = "ProductsSales")]
    public interface IProductsSales
    {

        [OperationContract]
        [WebGet(UriTemplate = "Orders/{orderID}", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        [Description("Returns the details of an order")]
        SalesOrderHeader GetOrder(string orderID);

    }
}
```

**ProductSales**

```
public SalesOrderHeader GetOrder(string orderID)
{
    SalesOrderHeader header = null;

    try
    {
        int id = Convert.ToInt32(orderID);
        AdventureWorksEntities database = new AdventureWorksEntities();

            header = (from order in database.SalesOrderHeaders
                      where order.SalesOrderID == id
                      select order).FirstOrDefault();

    }
    catch
    {
        throw new WebFaultException(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }

    return header;
}
```

I am working through an sample in a WCF book so they had me build a small console application to be the host, so this is the app.config file I have for the host client.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="AdventureWorksEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/ProductsSalesModel.csdl|res://*/ProductsSalesModel.ssdl|res://*/ProductsSalesModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=BINGBONG;Initial Catalog=AdventureWorks;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
<startup><supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/></startup><system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="ProductsSalesService.ProductsSales">
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:8000/Sales" binding="webHttpBinding"
          bindingConfiguration="" name="ProductsSalesService.ProductsSales"
          contract="ProductsSalesService.IProductsSales" />
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Finally, this is just the host client code.

```
public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            WebServiceHost host = new WebServiceHost(typeof(ProductsSalesService.ProductsSales));
            host.Open();
            Console.WriteLine("Service running");
            Console.WriteLine("Press ENTER to stop the service");
            Console.ReadLine();
            host.Close();
        }
    }
```

So when I go to `http://localhost:8000/Sales/Orders/43659` to pull up my order it hits three times and the page cancels in Chrome with the following error:

> This webpage is not available The connection to localhost was
>   interrupted. Here are some suggestions: Reload this webpage later.
>   Check your Internet connection. Restart any router, modem, or other
>   network devices you may be using. Add Google Chrome as a permitted
>   program in your firewall's or antivirus software's settings. If it is
>   already a permitted program, try deleting it from the list of
>   permitted programs and adding it again. If you use a proxy server,
>   check your proxy settings or contact your network administrator to
>   make sure the proxy server is working. If you don't believe you should
>   be using a proxy server, adjust your proxy settings: Go to the wrench
>   menu > Settings > Show advanced settings... > Change proxy settings...
>
> > LAN Settings and deselect the "Use a proxy server for your LAN" checkbox. Error 101 (net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET): The connection was
> >     reset.

If I remove the `WebMessageFormat.Json` everything works fine!

Thanks for any assistance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For starters try WCF tracing/logging to see if it sheds any light on things.

Put this in your server's config file (somewhere within the `<configuration>` element):-

```
<system.diagnostics>
 <sources>
  <source name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Error" propagateActivity="true">
    <listeners>
      <add name="traceListener" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener" initializeData="C:\Temp\server.svclog"/>
    </listeners>
  </source>
  <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging">
    <listeners>
      <add name="messages"
      type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
      initializeData="C:\Temp\server_messages.svclog" />
    </listeners>
  </source>
 </sources>
</system.diagnostics>
```

And put this inside the `<system.serviceModel>` element:-

```
<diagnostics>
  <messageLogging
       logEntireMessage="true"
       logMalformedMessages="false"
       logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true"
       logMessagesAtTransportLevel="false"
       maxMessagesToLog="3000"
       maxSizeOfMessageToLog="2000"/>
</diagnostics>
```

Try hitting your service again and examine the .svclog files that this (hopefully) generates for clues. The files will open in a "Service Trace Viewer" tool - if not it can be downloaded from MS (part of the Win SDK I think).

Comment: The diagnostics revealed the real problem for me which was an exception I was receiving: "The type 'xxx' cannot be serialized to JSON because its IsReference setting is 'True'. The JSON format does not support references because there is no standardized format for representing references. To enable serialization, disable the IsReference setting on the type or an appropriate parent class of the type, meaning the native DataContractJsonSerializer of WCF cannot serialize Entity Framework objects.

Answer (score 1):

Although my fault is actually unrelated, this is the first article I found when looking into my problem which is that my service was failing and I was seeing an error **connection has been interrupted**.

My fault was to do with the fact that the class I was outputting from my `WebGet` method had properties that had `DataContract` attributes but I had not added a `Set` accessor to each one (because I considered them to be output-only I didn't see the point).

Adding the tracing into my configuration file quickly revealed that the fault was that there were no `Set` accessors, so I added `private set` accessors to each `DataContract` property and all is now working as expected.

*I have added this here in case anyone else follows the same search path and has the same issue*.

Answer (score 0):

This line of code will construct Service Host without taking configuration into account so you will have Service but it will listen different URL.

```
WebServiceHost host = new WebServiceHost(typeof(ProductsSalesService.ProductsSales));
```

Add base address `new WebServiceHost` plus code below:

```
    WebChannelFactory<ProductsSalesService.IProductsSales> cf = 
    new WebChannelFactory<ProductsSalesService.IProductsSales>("ProductsSalesService.ProductsSales");
ProductsSalesService.IProductsSales channel = cf.CreateChannel();
```

See full code here - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb919583