# Returning EF Model classes from WCF Service

Tags: wcf, entity-framework, datacontract

I have a DB first EF setup. I would like to return the results of queries and views with WCF services. I have the OperationContracts and the EF classes all have the DataContractAttribute. I can call the method and everything works fine until it goes to return a list of results, then the page goes to "Connection to localhost was interrupted."

I currently work-around this by having a set of DataContract classes that map to the EF classes and they return just fine.

Can anyone tell me how to fix this or why it's happening?

Comment: My guess is you have a serialization problem, but that is just a guess without seeing the code. See: http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2008/Nov/04/Debugging-a-WCF-RESTAJAX-Serialization-Problem and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11016228/rest-wcf-service-returns-xml-response-but-not-json-response

Answer (score 1):

If you're just using the normal code generation strategy for Entity Framework in database-first mode, then those entities cannot be serialized and deserialized, as they rely on the context (which will be destroyed after the call is complete and never exists on the client) to do change tracking.

You need to switch to [Self-Tracking Entities](http://robbincremers.me/2012/02/01/entity-framework-using-self-tracking-entities-in-a-multi-layered-architecture/).