# WCF service returns XML response when requesting json despite setting accept: application/json

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, serialization

I have a WCF service that returnsa simple DTO that looks almost like this:

```
    [DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(TimeTriggerCreateResult))]
[KnownType(typeof(ScheduleCreateResult))]
public class TriggerCreateResult
{
    [DataMember(Order = 1)] public bool AlreadyExisted;
    [DataMember(Order = 2)] public int SchedulerId; // TODO: rename to ScheduleId
    [DataMember(Order = 3, EmitDefaultValue = false)] public int TriggerId;
    [DataMember(Order = 4)] public ScheduleType ScheduleType;

    public NewSchedule Schedule;
}
[DataContract]
public class TimeTriggerCreateResult : TriggerCreateResult
{
    public TimeTriggerCreateResult()
    {
        ScheduleType = ScheduleType.TimeTrigger;
    }

    public TimeTriggerDto TimeTrigger;
    [DataMember] public List<DateTuple> NextRun;
    public List<DateTuple> OlderRuns;
}
[Description("Create Schedule")]
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "schedules/create")]
        TriggerCreateResult CreateNewSchedule(ScheduleDto scheduleDto);
[DataContract]
public enum ScheduleType
{
    [EnumMember] NoTrigger = 0,
    [EnumMember] TimeTrigger = 1,
}
```

This service does a lot of complicated stuff behind the scenes but returns the a little DTO with the corresponding properties mentioned in its definition.

I consume this service using the following key=>value in the header: `accept:application/json` but the irony is that I get an **XML response** when the service creates a new schedule. That is the first time a schedule is created, it returns an XML response. Wheras if the same schedule is attempted to be created again, then I get a **JSON response**, i.e. if the schedule already existed in the database. We do not manually serialize in different response formats. We solely rely on WCF's serialization/deserialization.

I have tried answers like [REST WCF service returns XML response but not JSON response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11016228/rest-wcf-service-returns-xml-response-but-not-json-response) to trace the problem, but haven't got any useful information out of it. I have wasted two days entirely trying different combinations like:

- Adding `KnownTypes(typeof(ScheduleType))` to the `TriggerCreateResult` DTO just in case this was a serialization problem. But if it was a serialization problem, wouldn't it have thrown an exception?
- Because it always returned a json when the schedule already existed in the database, I tried setting `AlreadyExisted` to `true`, but that didn't help at all.
- I can mask the problem and always force a `json` response by using the `RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json` in the `WebInvoke` of the operationcontract declaration. And also by making sure that all the enumeration types used in the DTO, `ScheduleType` is decorated with a `DataContract` attribute and has its members declared as `EnumMember`. But then again, even though **the response is a JSON** as expected **the response header contains**, `Content-Type: application/xml`.

But I want to know what is causing this automatic XML serialization when JSON format is requested even when no serialization exception is encountered. I know this because we tried logging and tracing as mentioned in one of the other questions. It just silently gives a response with HTTP 200 but return XML data instead of JSON data when what is expected is JSON.

What makes this weird is that, this service had always returned a `JSON` response whenever it was requested to return so, but a recent change introduced the enum property ScheduleType which is being initialized to a particular type inside the constructor of the corresponding DTO, example inside `TimeTriggerCreateResult` it is initialized ot `TimeTrigger`. Ever since, it has been behaving weird. The response of the service thereafter has been in an XML format, when it created a new schedule that never existed in the DB and when this happens, the bool AlreadyExisted would have the value of `false`. But if the same request was done again, then it returns a JSON response, but with AlreadyExisted, now being `true`.

A sample xml response:

[image]

I'm not an expert in all things WCF. SO I'd like to know what can cause the WCF serialization to silently return an XML when a JSON is requested for.

I have wasted considerable time (about 5-6 hours) trying to understand what is going on by testing various different settings. I wouldn't want to make a web.config change for this as this is the only service affected by this magical behaviour. But I have failed miserably to understand this rather unnatural phenomenon. Please help if you have any ideas.

Comment: What's the content of XML response?

Comment: the XML response is a valid deserialized response of the TimeTriggerCreateResult DTO in an XML format. Do you want a sample content?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to add

```
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="endpointBehavior">
      <enableWebScript />
      <webHttp defaultBodyStyle="Wrapped" defaultOutgoingResponseFormat="Json" />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
```

To `<system.serviceModel> <behaviors>` section

Comment: I really appreciate your suggestion. 
What I'm really trying to understand is why would WCF serialization return an XML when I request a JSON. I wouldn't want to change the default endpoint behaviour to JSON as other services in the project are fetched as XML.

Comment: It's a default shape of the message formatter. Using a behavior you are changing the shape of this channel message formatter.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the format of the response to be based on the accept header of the request, then you need to set the AutomaticFormatSelectionEnabled property of the WebHttpEndpoint or WebHttpBehaviour.

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <behaviors> 
    <endpointBehaviors> 
      <behavior> 
        <webHttp automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true" /> 
      </behavior> 
    </endpointBehaviors>
  </behaviors> 
  <standardEndpoints>  
    <webHttpEndpoint> 
      <!-- the "" standard endpoint is used by WebServiceHost for auto creating a web endpoint. --> 
      <standardEndpoint name="" helpEnabled="true" />
    </webHttpEndpoint>
  </standardEndpoints> 
</system.serviceModel>
```

See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee476510(v=vs.110).aspx) for further details. The best format to use is determined by checking the following in order

1. The media types in the request message’s Accept header.
2. The content-type of the request message.
3. The default format setting in the operation.
4. The default format setting in the WebHttpBehavior.